# Função de busca para Sql Server

Tags: sql

Gostaria de saber se tem uma função ou se poderia ser feito com um `select`, a busca pelo campo e-mail de uma tabela . Exemplo:

```
select PPESSOA.EMAIL from PPESSOA where PPESSOA.NOME like 
'ABNER FONTOURA C,RÊA'
'ADAILTON PEREIRA DE SOUZA' 
'ADALBERTO ROMUALDO PEREIRA HENRIQUE',
'ADELINA MARIA GOMES SCHETTINI ' ,
'ADELINA MARIA VASCONCELOS DE OLIVEIRA ' ,
'ADELLE KARINNE NASCIMENTO SILVA' ,
'ADEMIR VIEIRA DE MELO GARCIA' ,
'ADENILSON OLIVEIRA ANDRADE' ,
'ADENILSON ROBERTO JOSE PEREIRA' ,
'ADILLO LUIZ FARIA MEZZOMO' ,
'ADILSON DA SILVA ALVES ',
'ADILSON MARCOS MENDES ' ,
'ADMILSO ANTONIO DA SILVA ' ,
'ADMILSON SILVA FINTELMAN ' ,
'ADRIANA ALMEIDA DE SOUZA ' ,
'ADRIANA APARECIDA ALVES DE FREITAS ' ,
'ADRIANA APARECIDA CAETANO DA SILVA ' ,
```

e tem mais 3000 registros..

Como eu faço?

Comment: Esses 3000 registros estão em uma outra tabela?

Comment: De mais informações, porque esses caras serão selecionados, o que eles tem em comun...

Comment: Desculpem se nao soube informar, mas estão todos na mesma tabela.. eu fiz o select dessa maneira: select PPESSOA.EMAIL from PPESSOA where PPESSOA.NOME IN ('nome1', 'nome2',...)
so que existe espaços entre as aspas e o Sql nao esta retornando o resultado devido a estes espaços entre o nome e as aspas; 'nome1    ',

Comment: @Felipe por que você está buscando por nome? Qual a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: Usa o localizar e substituir, substitui o `espaço`+`apostrofe` por apenas uma `apostrofe`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177827.aspx) e [`RTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178660.aspx) em cada ocorrência para evitar os espaços da seguinte forma:

```
select PPESSOA.EMAIL from PPESSOA where PPESSOA.NOME in ( 
ltrim(rtrim('ABNER FONTOURA C,RÊA')),
ltrim(rtrim('ADAILTON PEREIRA DE SOUZA')),
ltrim(rtrim('ADALBERTO ROMUALDO PEREIRA HENRIQUE')),
...
);
```

Comment: eu tentei usar o Ltrim, so que eu teria que fazer isso para cada nome, então levaria muito tempo. Obrigado mesmo.
Eu consegui criar uma substituição parecida com o que o LucasMotta indicou. Obrigado Lucas,
eu fiz de outra forma, usando o word.. deu um trabalhão, mas acabei de conseguir fazer.
Agradeço muito a todos pela ajuda.